# WPF - Binding to collection in object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, collections

I was trying to get it working for few days.
What is wrong in this code?

This is my window XAML:

```xml
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Rapideo_Client"
        x:Class="Rapideo_Client.MainWindow"     
        Title="NVM" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="400" Width="625">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="linksTemplate" DataType="DownloadLink">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=SizeInMB}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Url}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources> 
        <ListView   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    x:Name="MainListBox"
                    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource linksTemplate}">                
        </ListView>
</Window>
```

This is my class:

```
class Rapideo
    {
        (...)
        public List<DownloadLink> Links { get; private set; }
        (...)
    }
```

This is my item:

```
class DownloadLink
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Url { get; private set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; private set; }
    public float SizeInMB { get; private set; }
    public int Path { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public LinkState State { get; set; }
    public enum LinkState
    {
        Ready, Downloading, Prepering, Downloaded
    }

    public DownloadLink(string name, string url, DateTime expiryDate, float sizeInMB, int path, string value, LinkState state)
    {
        Name = name;
        Url = url;
        ExpiryDate = expiryDate;
        SizeInMB = sizeInMB;
        Path = path;
        Value = value;
        State = state;
    }
}
```

This is my binding:

```
RapideoAccount = new Rapideo();
MainListBox.ItemsSource = RapideoAccount.Links;
```

Later in the code I populate that list in RapideoAccount.Links.
But nothing is showing in ListView.
List View is always empty.

Where is mistake in that code?

Comment: Does your list start off empty?

Comment: shouldn't you bind to a dependency property, and shouldn't you bind to an observablecollection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx

Comment: You should not use a `ListView` if you don't use its View property, and you should not use its ItemTemplate property either. Use a `ListBox` instead, there you *should* use said property. Also, if you specify a DataType do it properly, yours lacks the xmlns prefix it requires.

Comment: @Daniel Williams yes, it's empty.

Comment: See [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be an `ObservableCollection<DownloadLink>` if you're planning on adding to it AFTER you have setup the `ItemsSource`. If the list is preloaded and you won't be changing it, `List<T>` would have worked.

Now I do think that

```
MainListBox.ItemsSource = RapideoAccount.Links;
```

is still technically a binding. But what you are probably thinking of is binding via the DataContext rather than directly (al la MVVM style). So that'd be:

```
RapideoAccount = new Rapideo();
this.DataContext = RapideoAccount;
```

Then in your window, you'd bind your ItemSource like this:

```xml
<Window
    ...
    <ListView  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
               x:Name="MainListBox"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Links}" 
               ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource linksTemplate}">                
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that Links needs to be an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), not a List.

Comment: After changing everything to ObservableCollection it is still not working.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce it, but cannot - my code works.  Is DownloadLink a public class?  If I make mine non-public (private by default), then I cannot even compile the code.

Comment: Aha - if you simply update the list, it will do nothing.  you need to redo the assignment: MainListBox.ItemsSource = RapideoAccount.Links; after you have updated the links.  This is not true binding, but will get it done.  Also - you CAN use a list - no need for Observable collection.  Binding would require more...

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should use an `ObservableCollection<DownloadLink>` rather than a `List<DownloadLink>` if you're planning on making changes to the list after setting up the binding.

Second of all, just to be clear:

```
MainListBox.ItemsSource = RapideoAccount.Links;
```

is not a binding. You're just setting the property. That will work for certain scenarios, but its not really a binding like we normally talk about in WPF.

Comment: @Hooch: In XAML: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RapidioAccounts.Links}"`.  That would assume that your DataContext has a `RapidioAccounts` property.  If it does not then you will need to set the `Source` as well.