# Populating a datagrid using a OleDbCommand and maintaining the items source once connection is closed

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, oledbcommand

I've got the code below to populate a datagrid in a C# WPF application. I've been told that I should "Close" the connection as soon as I have retrieved the data I need. However once the connection has been closed so does the reader and I lose the itemsource for my datagrid. How would I maintain the contents of this datagrid once I close the connection and reader? To clarify, once the data has been retrieved the datagrid contents won't change.

Code:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = DataBase.ConnectionString() };
conn.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader = null;

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID],[ClassName] FROM Class WHERE TeacherID = @TeacherID", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherID", Properties.Settings.Default.UserID);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

_ClassGrid.ItemsSource = reader;    //_ClassGrid is my DataGrid

conn.Close();
```

The code will function fine, if I remove the `conn.close();`

Thanks for any help in advance, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I do more VB work, but I believe you need to fill the datagrid before closing the connection.

Comment: Did I not fill the datagrid when I set the itemsource? `_ClassGrid.ItemsSource = reader; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you are displaying data, you need to "bind" or set your item source to a disconnected object, and not the data source directly.  You should also ensure that you dispose of all disposable objects in your code.  If you do not have a lot of data, the simplest thing to do would be use fill a datatable.  If you do have a lot of data, then you should use POCO's in a collection.  The following code shows for a datatable:

```
DataTable stuffToDisplay = new DataTable();
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = DataBase.ConnectionString() })
{
    conn.Open();

    using(var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID],[ClassName] FROM Class WHERE TeacherID = @TeacherID", conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherID", Properties.Settings.Default.UserID);

        using(var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            adapter.Fill(stuffToDisplay);
        }
    }
}

// Looks like you need to set to default view in WPF
_ClassGrid.ItemsSource = stuffToDisplay.DefaultView;
```

That is kind of a rough cut, so take that with a grain of debugging salt.  But give something like that a shot.  Here is a link to the data adapter class on MSDN, it should give you some idea of how to use it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

If you do have a lot of data, then you should consider using objects instead of a data table (I think that is more excepted anyways).  I would do some reading on binding and observable collections to get your WPF right for that situation, using a data reader to fill objects (or entity framework).  Here are some related questions to that, which would be faster than me posting a ton of code on it.

[WPF - Binding to collection in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131504/wpf-binding-to-collection-in-object)

[Bind collection of objects to ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452502/bind-collection-of-objects-to-listbox)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1f211699-5764-47ae-9ad9-d9ff2875e9c0/how-to-set-listboxitemssource-to-a-collection-of-objects-in-xaml?forum=wpf

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I appear to get an error when trying to set the itemsource equals to the datatable. It states:

` Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. `

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry bind the item source to the "DefaultView" property of the Datatable

Comment: Or set the "DataContext" to the datatable and not the ItemsSource.  I don't have an IDE in front of me, I know one of those should work

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, as suggested I changed it to :
` _ClassGrid.ItemsSource = stuffToDisplay.DefaultView;`
and it's now working great!