# Connect database OLE with gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I work in Visual Studio 2010. It creates a data segment and shows it in a ready view without using SQL connection to access the SQL Server database.

I wrote the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WebApplication16
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data/Database1.mdf;"));
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Emp", conn);
                conn.Open();

                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXg5d.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wew5b.png)

I was hoping that it would display a table of the contents of the database that I had created manually

Comment: When you try to run (hitting f5), what is the error message,?

Answer (score 0):

Your gridview is not populating because you are not passing it data in a format it can understand. [You need to use a datatable to populate your gridview from your oledbconnection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243272/populating-a-datagrid-using-a-oledbcommand-and-maintaining-the-items-source-once) You should also open your db connections inside of a Using block and generally speaking it is best practice not to do all of that in your pageLoad as you now see below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WebApplication16
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    Private String connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={Server.MapPath("App_Data/Database1.mdf;")}";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               Set_GridView_DataSource();
            }
        }
    }
}

    Private void Set_GridView_DataSource() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable()
        Using OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString) {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Emp", conn);
            conn.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            dataAdapter.fill(dt);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Actually, you can pass a data bound control a reader. However, it not a great idea, since then in the row data bind event, you can't get use of the full data row - including columns that don't exist in the markup/Gridview. However, worse here is the user has a JET/ACE (ms-access) path name to a mdf file (sql server). That's not going to work for the poster at all. Poster needs to get SQL express installed. And furthermore, the poster REALLY should use the SqlProvider, and not the oleDB one. So, the user's connection string is all wrong, and is for ms-access, not SQL server.